# Error Message when Scheduling a Meeting from Team Client

Tags: microsoft-teams

when scheduling a Meeting from the Team client. We receive a NDR complaining about “Remote Server returned '550 5.7.708 Service unavailable. Access denied, traffic not accepted from this IP. Scheduling from outlook web and client works fine without any issue.

Comment: Could you please provide the  tenant ID and name, MS Diagnostic logs captured at the moment of issue, Fiddler traces captured at the time of issue so we can look into this issue?

Comment: Are you interacting with the Microsoft Teams client programmatically via e.g. an API? Or is this an error you're getting when using the normal interface? It sounds like the latter, since there isn't any code or mention of automation. If so, this probably makes more sense in [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/)—if not being raised directly with Microsoft via their support channels.

Comment: We need the above details to look into this issue. Please help us with the details asked.